# Vue Dynamic component is not been re rendered

Tags: vue.js

I have a basic component for all my input fields that wraps a dynamic component.

```
<my-input v-model="book_id" as="select" :options="availableBooks"
            label="Books" :dirty="changed.includes('book_id')"/>
```

I use a computed property to feed that component.

```
availableBooks () {
  if(this.books.length === 0) {
    return [{id: '1', text: 'test1'}]
  } else {
    return [{id: '2', text: 'test2'}]
  }
}
```

Inside my-input component, I render dynamically a component /my-input.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="live-input" :class="cssClass">
   <component :is="inputType" :state="currentState" :value="value" :errors="errors"
           v-on="$listeners" v-bind="$attrs" class="d-inline-block"/>
  </div>
</template>

props: {
  as: { type: String, default: 'text' },
  label: { type: String },
  hint: { type: String },
  inline: { type: Boolean, default: false },
},

data() {
  return {
    inputType: this.as || TextInput,
    currentDirty: this.dirty,
    selfUpdate: false,
  }
}
```

Then I have a second component select select-input.vue

```
<template>
   <b-select :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event)" 
              ref="input" :state="state" :options="optionsForSelect"/>
</template>

props: {
  options: { type: Array },
},

data() {
  const sampleOption = this.options[0]
  const valueMethod = tryProperties(sampleOption, ['value', 'id'])
  const textMethod = tryProperties(sampleOption, 
                       ['text', 'name', 'label', 'toS']
                     )

return {
  localOptions: this.options,
  optionsForSelect: this.options.map(option => {
    if (typeof option === 'string') {
      return { value: option, text: option }
    } else {
      return {value: option[valueMethod], text: option[textMethod]}
    }
  }),
}
},
```

First this.books.length equals to zero, then I updated async and it has some entries, When I trace the availableBooks object seems that is been updated correctly but the select dropdown is not been updated.

Also seems that prop options has been updated but still the component is not been rerendered.

```
watch: {
  options: function(newVal, oldVal) { // [{id: '2', text: 'test2'}]
    console.log('Prop changed: ', newVal, ' | was: ', oldVal)
  }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get updates for the `options` prop in order to re-render your component when `options` changes, you should use a `computed` attribute for `optionsForSelect` instead of a `data` one. When using `data` the value gets copied in the component and will only get re-rendered when the `data` attribute is changed locally.

If you use a `computed` property, when the parent component changes the prop `options` value, the `computed` attribute will get re-evaluated and your component will render again.

```
computed: {
   optionsForSelect() {
       if (typeof option === 'string') {
           return { value: option, text: option }
       } else {
          return {value: option[valueMethod], text: option[textMethod]}
       }
   }
}
```

The `computed` property would be my preferred approach.

However, you can also accomplish this with the `data` attribute you have. You would have to add a watcher for the `options` prop and assign the new value each time the prop is updated to `optionsForSelect` data attribute.

```
watch: {
    options: function(newVal, oldVal) {
        // Update this.optionsForSelect value here
   }
}
```

Hope  it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Once that have entered the WATCH function, you can update the select-input view with **this.$forceUpdate()**.

```
watch: {
  options: function(newVal, oldVal) { // [{id: '2', text: 'test2'}]
    // console.log('Prop changed: ', newVal, ' | was: ', oldVal)
    this.$forceUpdate()
  }
}
```